# Microphone issues on debian 10

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, alsamixer

I'm trying to set up discord chat with debian 10 installed on macbook pro. there are two input devices listed in discord. Default, and Built-in Audio Analog Stereo. I was using Default, and it worked fine. When I shut the computer down and started it back up the next day, discord says that it can't detect any input from my mic. I just want to use my built-in laptop mic.

`alsamixer`:
[image]
`sudo alsamixer`:
[image]
[image]
What should I change?

EDIT: Also: why is the "Mic" level empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did a `sudo alsactl init` then changed my volumes back to how I wanted them, and it all worked.

Answer (score 1):

First I tried:

```
felipe@SDF-1:~$ apulse
felipe@SDF-1:~$ sudo apt-get install  tetraproc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libclthreads2 libclxclient3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libclthreads2 libclxclient3 tetraproc
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 111 kB of archives.
After this operation, 390 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`I installed the whole Alsa
```

It didn't work.

then, I tried:

```
felipe@SDF-1:~$ sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  hyphen-en-us libpulsedsp libreoffice-help-common libreoffice-help-en-us
  mythes-en-us node-normalize.css pulseaudio-utils rtkit
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome* gnome-core* libcanberra-pulse* pulseaudio*
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth* task-gnome-desktop*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 6,953 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 233627 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gnome (1:3.30+1) ...
Removing task-gnome-desktop (3.53) ...
Removing gnome-core (1:3.30+1) ...
Removing libcanberra-pulse:amd64 (0.30-7) ...
Removing pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (12.2-4+deb10u1) ...
Removing pulseaudio (12.2-4+deb10u1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
(Reading database ... 233381 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for pulseaudio (12.2-4+deb10u1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-0+deb10u1) ...
```

just like that... to kill it...

then,

```
felipe@SDF-1:~$ 
felipe@SDF-1:~$ sudo alsactl init
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Conexant CX20549 (Venice)" "HDA:14f15045,103c30cd,00100100" "0x103c" "0x30cd"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
felipe@SDF-1:~$ alsamixer
felipe@SDF-1:~$ 
felipe@SDF-1:~$ 
felipe@SDF-1:~$ 
felipe@SDF-1:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  hyphen-en-us libpulsedsp libreoffice-help-common libreoffice-help-en-us
  mythes-en-us node-normalize.css pulseaudio-utils rtkit
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 8 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 51.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 233376 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing hyphen-en-us (2.8.8-7) ...
Removing pulseaudio-utils (12.2-4+deb10u1) ...
Removing libpulsedsp:amd64 (12.2-4+deb10u1) ...
Removing libreoffice-help-en-us (1:6.1.5-3+deb10u7) ...
Removing libreoffice-help-common (1:6.1.5-3+deb10u7) ...
Removing mythes-en-us (1:6.2.0-1) ...
Removing node-normalize.css (8.0.1-3) ...
Removing rtkit (0.11-6) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-0+deb10u1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
felipe@SDF-1:~$
```

Now the microphone is working.

Comment: why so many empty terminal lines? also, you don't need to post the entire output of apt commands